# scrolling down when using JQuery slidetoggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 footer (footer-larg) & (footer-bottom) i need when i click a link in footer-bottom (flip) .. footer-larg toggle && scroll down to footer-bottom

until now footer-larg toggle but not scroll down

```
$("#flip").click(function() {
        $("#footer-large").slideToggle("slow");
                    if ($("#footer-large").is(':visible')) {
                        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#footer-large").offset().top});
                     }                       
    });
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using animation to scroll the document as this can lead to odd results when the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why not let the browser handle the scroll?

Try this:

```
$("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#footer-large").slideToggle("slow");
    if ($("#footer-large").is(':visible')) {
        window.location = '#footer-large';
    }                       
});
```